# My code is not running. This code is the famous "FizzBuzz" question

Tags: swift, function, fizzbuzz

I am trying to run this code but it's not working. I don't know how to return the input j as a string.
This is the error
/tmp/D2FFE31F-B533-48DF-AC15-F1EA8A029FCF.q0h9za/main.swift:15:1: error: missing return in a function expected to return 'String'

```
func FizzBuzz(j:Int) -> String {
if j % 5 == 0 && j % 3 == 0 {
    return "FizzBuzz"
}

else if j % 3 == 0 {
    return "Buzz"
}

else if j % 5 == 0 {
    return "Fizz"
}
}

for i in 0...100 {
print(FizzBuzz(j:i))
}
```

Comment: Didn't downvote, but you're missing a `)` at the end of `print(FizzBuzz(j:i)`

Comment: Sorry Aheze i did it in the IDE but I guess it didn't load. But if you want to know the error this is it.     /tmp/D2FFE31F-B533-48DF-AC15-F1EA8A029FCF.q0h9za/main.swift:15:1: error: missing return in a function expected to return 'String'

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I do think your question could be improved. In particular, you should change the title to something more specific, like "convert Int to String".

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @rob mayoff's answer, the problem is also that you **must** `return` a string in that function, because you said so:

```
                        // must return a String
func FizzBuzz(j:Int) -> String {
```

So look in your function. What if `j` is not divisible by 5, or 3? Your code will just fall through the `if else`, and none of the `return`s will be called.

To fix this, just do a return at the end of your function.

```
func FizzBuzz(j:Int) -> String {
    if j % 5 == 0 && j % 3 == 0 {
        return "FizzBuzz"
    } else if j % 3 == 0 {
        return "Buzz"
    } else if j % 5 == 0 {
        return "Fizz"
    }

    return "\(j)" /// return the number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift strings have a feature called [“string interpolation”](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID292). When a string contains the characters `\(` followed by some expression followed by `)`, Swift evaluates (runs) the expression and converts the result to a string, and substitutes that result string into the enclosing string. For example:

```
"two plus three is \(2 + 3)"
```

Above, Swift computes `2 + 3`, getting the `Int` `5`, then converts the `Int` `5` into the string `"5"`, then substitutes that into the enclosing string, getting `"two plus three is 5"`.

So one way to return `j` as a string is to use string interpolation like this:

```
return "\(j)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: “if” statements always need an “else” to return a result.

You have 3 if/else if statements, but no final “else” if those fail.

You need to add either

```
else {
   return “”
}
```

Or just a final

```
return “”
```